# Clearly show an image/button is clickable/touchable

Tags: image, button, click, touch

Hey i am building an interface to display power flow and I have images for controllers (switches, power storage, etc...) some of the images contain more information (pop-ups) and some do not I am looking for a way to clearly show the images with more content I was wondering if anyone has good idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a web page, [clickable text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097307/427192) is often in a different color and/or is underlined.  Perhaps you can do something similar?  Add a colored border to your images-with-more-content?